# Backend of ms access (2019) database table on sharepoint with autonumber wish to make random instead of increment

Tags: vba, ms-access, sharepoint

Question,
Can I change the property of autonumber a linked table in msaccess from increment to random.
(I use an appendquery to update the local database to the sharepoint database in ms access.)
Please can you help me?

Comment: I don't think so https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Auto-Number-to-SharePoint-List/td-p/117976

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't believe you can change this.
In fact, you can't even have a linked Access to SharePoint without a autonumber, and in fact quite sure it even has to be "ID".

And you can't even have a table without a autonumber "ID". This is  SharePoint issue.

Comment: Thank you fro Resonse, I found a solution to use One Drive or Google drive, I put the backend on google drive and I use an append query to udate my local (offline) database. That is why I need random autonumbers

Comment: But random numbers don't prevent others from generating the same numbers, and thus a collision over time will occur